# How to return list dto when using select new

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I using spring boot and i using select new return dto because i don't want return my entity. But when i return List it not working. It throw me exception :

```
 "timestamp": "2019-05-14T14:06:06.762+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No converter found capable of converting from type [com.abc.demospringjpa.dto.CategoryResDto] to type [com.abc.demospringjpa.model.CategoryResDtoList]",
```

Category Model.

```
package com.abc.demospringjpa.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
//@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Category implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
}
```

**Controller.**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/categories")
public class CategoryController {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;
//
//    @GetMapping
//    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllCategory() {
//        return new ResponseEntity<>(categoryService.findAllCategory(), HttpStatus.OK);
//    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public CategoryResDto findCategoryByName(@PathVariable("id")Long id) {
        return categoryService.findCategoryByName(id);
    }

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<?> findCategoryByName(@RequestParam("type")String type) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(categoryService.findCategoryByType(type), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
//
//    @GetMapping
//    public ResponseEntity<?> saveCategory() {
//        return new ResponseEntity<>(categoryService.saveCa(), HttpStatus.OK);
//    }
 }
```

**Service**

```
public interface CategoryService {
    List<CategoryResDto> findAllCategory();
    CategoryResDto findCategoryByName(Long name);
    CategoryResDtoList findCategoryByType(String type);
//    CategoryResDto saveCategory(Category category);
}
```

ServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {

    final
    CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    final
    CategoryMapper categoryMapper;

    @Autowired
    public CategoryServiceImpl(CategoryRepository categoryRepository, CategoryMapper categoryMapper) {
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        this.categoryMapper = categoryMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public List<CategoryResDto> findAllCategory() {
        return categoryRepository.findAll().stream().
                map(categoryMapper::categoryToCategoryDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public CategoryResDto findCategoryByName(Long id) {
        return categoryRepository.findAllCategoryById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public CategoryResDtoList findCategoryByType(String type) {
        return categoryRepository.findAllCategoryResponseDto(type);
    }
}
```

Repository.

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category,Long> {

    @Query(value = "Select new com.abc.demospringjpa.dto.CategoryResDto(c.name) from Category  c where c.id = :id")
    CategoryResDto findAllCategoryById(@Param("id") Long id);

    @Query(value = "Select new com.abc.demospringjpa.dto.CategoryResDto(c.name) from Category  c where c.type = :type")
    CategoryResDtoList findAllCategoryResponseDto(@Param("type")String type);
}
```

CategoryRes:

```
 @Data
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    //@NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class CategoryResDto {

        @JsonProperty("category_name")
        private String name;
    }





 CategoryResList:  
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Data
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public class CategoryResDtoList {

        private List<CategoryResDto> categoryResDtos;
    }
```

I want return CategoryResDtoList because it contain CategoryResDto . It possible ?  When i excute  and call method, it throw me exception :

```
 "timestamp": "2019-05-14T14:06:06.762+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No converter found capable of converting from type [com.abc.demospringjpa.dto.CategoryResDto] to type [com.abc.demospringjpa.model.CategoryResDtoList]",
```

I have a question: how to i using Select new return my DTO CategoryResDtoList instead  `List<CategoryResDto`> because i want custom some message return

Comment: You'd better directly return a `List<CategoryResDto>` .

Comment: `CategoryResDtoList` != `CategoryResDto`

Comment: because i want rename some field when return . Example : I want rename listCategory return with name "category_name" when i using : @Jsonproperty. It possible return  CategoryResDtoList ?

Comment: Have you tried with `@NoArgsConstructor` on `CategoryResDtoList`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `CategoryResList`, return `List<CategoryResDto>` directly.